# How does the [ng\:cloak] selector format work?

Tags: css, angularjs

The documentation for ngCloak lists the [ng\:cloak] selector in the AngularJS CSS file. I understand how the function of ngCloak works, but I don't understand this weird [x\:y] format that's used in the CSS file.